# Maximum Value of subarray

Tags: max, pascal, freepascal, arrays

Is there any function that returns the maximum number from a subarray of a longint array?

For example:

I have the array: [2,3,6,2,9,4,2,4]

I want the maximum value of the first 5 elements [2,3,6,2,9] of the array (9)

Which is the best solution?

Comment: Best solution is the one that you made up ;)

Comment: i know...
I was thinking to make a loop that fills an another array with the elements that i need to find the max but i don't know if this is the best solution :(

Comment: Simply declare a variable that will hold that max value. Then loop through the array and compare the current element value against that variable. If it's greater, store the element value to that variable. If not, move on.

Comment: Is this the optimal solution?
(i am sure that this it's better than my idea :P)

Comment: If your array is not sorted, it is the only way I can think of.

Comment: You're welcome! Out of curiosity, if you would need to find out the max, or min value from from the whole array, you could use [`MaxIntValue`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/maxintvalue.html), or [`MinIntValue`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/minintvalue.html) functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create another array.
The 1st solution that would come up is to loop inside your array, taking the first value as 'tempMaxValue', and then fetching your array comparing each value to the 'tempMaxValue'.

If the value is greater than 'tempMaxValue', update 'tempMaxValue' with that particular value and then jump to the next value in the array, otherwise just jump to the next value.

With this solution, you can manage the number of items you want to search into (here you wanted the greatest number within the 5 first elements, so your loop will go from 0 to 4)

Edit : (as @TLama said)

Answer (score 0):

More concretly this is the easy solution: write a function which takes an array, the lowest and the highest indexes as parameter.

```
program Project1;

uses sysutils;

type TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

function maxInRange(const anArr: TIntegerArray; boundLow, boundHi: Integer): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := anArr[boundLow];
  for i := boundLow + 1 to boundHi do
    if anArr[i] > result then
      result := anArr[i];
end;

const
  arr: array[0..7] of Integer = (2,3,6,2,9,4,2,4);

begin
  writeln(intToStr(maxInRange(arr,0,4)));
  readln;
end.
```